# Spring boot logging.file does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> logging.file=logs/spring-boot-logging.log

It work localy on my machine but where can I find this file on remote server?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by *It work locally on my machine* ? You are invoking it through Eclipse ? or from a console? Where does Spring Boot Create the file when you running it locally? In the same place , it should create it when you're running it on a remote machine , except of course , if you don't give the permissions to the Spring Boot App in order to write/create a file on the remote machine

Comment: yes I see file in eclipse D:\Exampleproject\logs, on remote machine(https://www.dailyrazor.com/) file is not created at all

Comment: yeap probably because the user which you are starting Tomcat or the SpringBoot  app , does not have permissions to create a file. As the others mentioned in their answers , try defining a default log file , which you have already created in the desired directory

Answer (score 2):

The path is relative to the current directory of your processes. It is best to use a more generic place such as `/var/log/<your-app>/spring-boot-logging.log`

Comment: I tried logging.file=/var/tomcat/logs/spring-boot-logging.log but nothing happen, I edited the question. Do I have to change any settings on the server side?

Comment: can I use something like ${catalina.home}/?

Comment: In order to log to /var/log/XXX your server process must have write permissions there. Do you use tomcat AND spring boot? If so why? Spring boot embeds the tomcat in your application

Comment: I use both. I mean tomcat manager for deployment spring boot. Is it bad practice?

Comment: I've never used it, usually I package a zip/tgz with the jar and the scripts, and deploy using ansible. Can you please check if the /var/log/YourApp directory exists and that the tomcat user has write permission to it? (I assume the service is running under this user§)

Answer (score 1):

It will depend wildly on the specifics of your server configuration. Set the environment variable `LOGGING_FILE` or the system property `logging.file` to an appropriate value on your server.